# How to map response to object in Angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to map a return result to an object in my app.  I've been away from Angular for about 2 years and have just started using it again.  The method I used before worked fine then, but something must have changed.  this.users is always undefined.

registration method calling getUserList:

```
users: IUser[] = [];    
getUserList() {

  this.lus.getUserList()
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.users = <IUser[]>result.json;
      console.log(result);
      console.log(this.users);
  },
  error => {
    throwError(this.listErrorHandler(error));
  },
  () => {
  })
```

IUser:

```
export interface IUser {
  userId: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

the return array:
[image]

this.users is always undefined.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out you don't need to use result.json.  Changing it to result worked like a charm.  Live and learn.